# HighScore Not Displaying In Menu Scene

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I have an app with a score and highscore system. I can display the highscore within the gameplay scene, but it shows up as 0 in the menu scene. In the gameplay scene I create the variable

```
var highScore = 0
```

then I say

```
if (score > highscore) { score = highscore
```

I display it inside that scene, I go back to the menu scene and it accesses it by saying

```
highscoreLabel = actionscene.highscore
```

(actionscene being the name of the file for my game play scene.) Since the 
original value of highscore is 0, it displays 0. How can I fix this or program it in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize) as an easiest solution. In the GameScene:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
 defaults.setInteger(10, forKey: "highscore")
 defaults.synchronize()
```

In another scene (MenuScene) :

```
 let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
 let highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
```

Also note that the `synchronize()` method, is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, and it keeps in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database.

Ideally, you would let the system to worry about when the persistent storage is updated, but there are cases when you want to do it by yourself and call synchronize() manually:

> Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals,
>   use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic
>   synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or
>   if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though
>   you have not made any changes.

Comment: That did not work. I have the defaults set up in the gamescene. I tried in the menuscene as well but it didn't work. It saves everytime I close and open the app, in the gamescene, it's justs when I reference highscore from the menuscene it thinks the value is 0 @Whirlwind

Comment: @JOSH Are you trying to save the score inside the GameScene and read it from the MenuScene ? Because that is what this code does, and it works for me...

Comment: sorry, I wrote your code incorrectly, I have it working now. Thanks so much! I truly appreciate it!

Comment: @JOSH Not a problem :) Glad to hear it working now. If this answer helped you to solve the issue, please mark it as accepted.